# Como fazer deploy de um projeto Asp.Net Core Web API no IIS?

Tags: servidor, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Olá, estou tentando colocar minha aplicação **ASP.NET WEB API** no IIS do servidor Windows Server 2016, porém sem sucesso.

Quando acesso a url ex: http://localhost:8080 retorna este erro:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure.

O processo que fiz até agora:

- Criei a aplicação
- apontei para o diretório onde está a aplicação
- apontei para a porta 8080
- Instalei no servidor o .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle
- mudei o ApplicationPool para: No Managed Code e Integrated
- No código do app coloquei o UseIISIntegration()

Realmente não sei o que pode estar causando o erro.

Já tentei diversas coisas que vi, inclusive no site da Microsoft. Não sei se estou fazendo algum processo errado

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Cara, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas vamos lá.
Você criou a aplicação no IIS?
Apontou o diretório da aplicação?
Apontou a porta que será utilizada? Se puder dar mais detalhes do caso seria legal.

Comment: Qual a versão `.NET Core` você está utilizando? Enquanto isso, veja se as [respostas desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38624453/4843158) lhe ajuda em algo

Comment: @Randrade , o problema era justamente a versão do .NET Core. No servidor eu instalei uma versão superior e por isso dava o erro.

Comment: @user1967120 Esse é um erro bastante comum. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido resolver e que postou a resposta para os demais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema estava ocorrendo devido a versão do .NET Core instalado no servidor e a versão utilizada no projeto.

Baixei a versão ideal no servidor equivalente a 1.0.5 que no caso era a **.NET Core 1.1.4 runtime (LTS) - Windows Server Hosting (x86/x64)**.

e o problema foi solucionado.